# MYSQL TO_DAYS() in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to write the following MYSQL code in Redshift but TO_DAYS() does not exist in Redshift. I tried AGE() as well but that didn't work.

```
SELECT 
     AVG(CASE WHEN s_status = 'finish' THEN (TO_DAYS(date1) - TO_DAYS(date2)) ELSE NULL 
         END) AS avg_time,
     SUM(CASE WHEN s_status = 'finish' AND (TO_DAYS(date1) - TO_DAYS(date2))<=7 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 END) AS one_week_time
FROM TABLE;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please don't throw every remotely related db tag into your question, your question really only needs the `amazon-redshift` tag (nb, even MySQL isn't actually needed to solve your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the date_diff() function which you can use to replace to_days() or replace the difference in to_days() with date_diff().

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html